# grub2 boot from ISO file on USB disk without BIOS support

Tags: boot, usb, iso-image, grub2

I've been looking for a while for an option to boot from an ISO file on a USB disk on an old machine whose BIOS doesn't support boot from USB....
I have already found a solution to config grub to boot from a bootable USB disk: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=992426
I also found a solution to boot from an ISO file with grub2: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples
Now I am looking for the combination of these two....
Any idea?

Comment: If the BIOS does not support boot from USB, there is nothng you can do, the hardware simply does not support it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't really true. There is a solution, if you install grub on the hardrive and configure it to boot from USB. I tested it, it works. The current problem is to boot from an iso file on the USB.

Comment: Just place the contents of the iso on the USB device and make the USB device bootable.